# Django model forms - disabled fields in changed_data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form base class which checks if the instance the form is updating has changed, and does not save if it has not changed.

this is in my custom model form, I override save:

```
class MyModelForm(models.ModelForm):
    # .. more code here..
        def save(self, commit=True):
            if self.has_changed():
               # Won't do anything if the instance did not changed
               return self.instance
            return super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit)
```

A LOT of my forms use this base class. 
Now, one of my forms have a few fields which I set to `disabled=True` (django 1.9 +). So in one of my forms:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      ## ..code
      self.fields['address'].disabled = True
```

After a lot of debugging why the `form.has_changed()` is True (hence the instance is saved for no reason), even when I save the form without changing the instance. I've found out that django includes disabled fields in `changed_data` - which makes no sense, as disabled fields should not be altered by the user anyway.

Am I missing something or it is a bug, or maybe that how it should work? 
How can I resolve this without too much changes, as the form base class is used a lot in my code.

Comment: I too have this question. Were you able to find a resolution?

Comment: Not exactly, I resolved it manually. i.e removed disabled fields from changed_data

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with DjangoProject with the ticket at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27431 and the corresponding PR at https://github.com/django/django/pull/7502. As this answer is being written the PR is merged with `master` so the latest version should have this fixed.

A workaround this is as follows

```
for form in formset:
    if form.has_changed() and form not in formset.deleted_forms:
        fields = form.changed_data
        up_f = [field for field in fields if not form.fields[field].disabled]
        if len(up_f) > 0:
            updated_data.append(form.cleaned_data)
```

This results in `updated_data` having the only forms that are updated and not deleted.